# How do I determine if a specific version of .Net framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Pro on a Win7. VS 2013 doesn't come with Framework 4.6.2, so I downloaded and installed it, then created my application. No problems. The application runs on my PC just fine.

I also created a ClickOnce installation. But v4.6.2 does not show up as an option in the Prerequisites dialog box, so if I try to install on a PC without framework 4.6.2 the installer complains and exits. If I install the framework manually, the installer works fine. Posting on MSDN has garnered no help.

So now I'm trying to create my own installer using Inno and I need to be able to determine if the right framework is installed. When I check the registry on my PC, the one I developed the application on, there is an entry for v4.0, which has one item named "deprecated", and one entry for v4. No entry for 4.6.2. Under v4 there are two sub-entries, Client and Full. Under both of those entries there is a Version entry with a value of 4.6.01590, an InstallPath entry with a value of c:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework64\v4.0.30319\, a TargetVersion entry with a value of 4.0.0, and an Install entry with a value of 1.

So, does anyone know how I determine if Framework 4.6.2 is installed?

Comment: If you google that (the last sentence almost verbatim) you will get many suitable answers. [Google - 'if Framework 4.6.2 is installed'](https://www.google.com/search?q=if+Framework+4.6.2+is+installed&oq=if+Framework+4.6.2+is+installed&aqs=chrome..69i57.807j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Is there a reason to build your own installer?  Shouldn't most installers have modules to check for the existence of the dependency, and install it if needed?

Comment: Did you try to download the [clickonce bootstrapper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48132) ?

Comment: I was building my own installer because Microsoft's didn't work, which is not uncommon. I've never liked their installers. And queries to the MSDN forums were ignored, again, not unusual for me. I was not aware of the Clickonce bootstrapper. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I downloaded and installed the clickonce bootstrapper. It added 4.6 to the Clickonce Prerequisites, but not 4.6.2.

Comment: I also googled 'if Framework 4.6.2 is installed' and the first entry in the results was the one I needed. I had done a search before, but used Bing. But it never found the right page, which I find odd since the webpage I needed was Microsoft's. With this new knowledge I completed my installer and it works great. So time to dump clickonce. Thank you all for the help.